# Bootstrapper with component selection

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

My application uses MySQL database which can be installed on local or remote computer. Therefore my installer should give possibility to choose if MySQL is to be installed alongside main application or not. As one installer cannot call another one, I need a bootstrapper. How can I add a checkbox to burn UI? I managed to add a checkbox to HyperlinkLicense page but I cannot make it used as a condition for ExePackage. Is it required to put the checkbox on Options page? As far as I know it's not possible to add custom pages.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment checkbox must be placed on Options page in order to have visible variable associated with this checkbox. If a checkbox is really needed on Install page, one needs custom BA, e.g. the one from http://wixextba.codeplex.com/